# If api response is zipForm then how to download or extract this zip response to csv file in react js

Tags: reactjs

Tried this button empty zip archive:

```
let blob = new Blob([data],{type: "text/plain"});
         saveAs(blob,'abc.zip')
```

Tried this but no csv file there there is zip file data coming as like as response

```
const zipData = res.data;
console.log(zipData);
zip.file("res.edi", res.data);

zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
           .then(function(content){
             saveAs(content, "example.zip");
           })
```

Please help me with this

Comment: what is `zip` in this code? (aka please read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and include all the details necessary to illustrate your problem using a [mcve] in your post)

Comment: zipData is . Coming as zip response from the api after uploading file

Comment: No, what is `zip`: you're calling `zip.file` and `zip.generateAsync` so what is that? Please update your code to make sure there's no mysteries: if you're using it, make sure it's clear what it is. (e.g. add the code that `require`s whatever that thing is, and mention which package and its version are. Without that, you're asking people to guess, and guesses are by definition not answers)